# error C2065: 'OCR_NORMAL' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, undeclared-identifier

I am using Visual Studio 2010 C++

How to remove this error?

```
error C2065: 'OCR_NORMAL' : undeclared identifier
```

near

```
wc.hCursor =
(HCURSOR)LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(OCR_NORMAL), IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_SHARED)
```

The answer is bellow: that helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7):

You need to define this macro:

```
#define OEMRESOURCE
```

just before you include windows.h